# What is the proper action if duplicate question is better than original?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Let's suppose that Question A is the original question, and question B is asking the same thing, but is clearly better presented. Should Question B be closed as duplicate?

Now let's suppose that Question B has generated answers that are also clearly better than answers to Question A, should question B still be closed as duplicate?

What is the proper action to fight duplicates, while not throwing away the additional value?

*I know that often it is hard to say what is "clearly" better, but for sake of this example let's suppose that the duplicate question and answers are indeed "clearly" better.

Comment: Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988640/what-is-the-difference-between-return-and-return

Comment: "The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place." from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). To help people find the best answers, close the original as a duplicate. I think this question is a duplicate, as I recall reading this advice on meta before.

Comment: Now that's what I call meta!

Comment: "Oh, the irony!" Is it an [official meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/163250) yet where a Meta question asking about duplicate questions gets closed as a duplicate of another Meta question?

Comment: I see, so the suggested solution is to close Question A. Why couldn't you guys come up with better answers than to the original question? Then we wouldn't have to close this one ;).