# Site policy regarding duplicates where first Google result is the duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, google

Over the past few months I've seen several questions where the first result on Google is the duplicate. Such questions often have critical comments along with the link to the original. However, **Google** promoted this question over the original.

Note this is not a duplicate of [What is the proper action if duplicate question is better than original?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254755/5276890), as there they discuss a clearly better answer marked as a dup.

I always feel a bit disconcerted when reading such questions. Despite the critical comments, these are useful questions. And so, I'll clarify: Are we happy with the situation where a question:

- ranked more highly on Google
- marked a duplicate
- neither better nor worse,
- carries a negative connotation

'Yes' is a legitimate answer here. I just thought I'd ask because I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Anonymous users (i.e. the vast majority of visitors to the site) get redirected immediately to the dupe target, so they never even see the original question.

Answer (score 8):

My google isn't like your google.  The first hit I see is not the duplicate, only the second.  Fretting over exactly how Google ranks and *personalizes* hits is rather pointless, it is a very well-kept secret and has changed many times.  Going by what it likes at a particular time for a particular user will cause endless debate.

Let's just keep our own.

Answer (score 2):

My first hit is not the duplicate either, but I'd like to bring **another way of looking at this**:

- **First hit: Original Post**

Say I search for what you've suggested and I found the original one, I read it all and I'm satisfied. Good. There is a possibility that some information might be left off, but it might be minimal.

- **First hit: DUP**

Now let's say there are some points addressed on the duplicate that **are not** on the original. By hitting the dup link, we have access to the original too. All the information is kinda added and we can choose to read from the other link (I don't know if we have access to the questions that reference to the original). That way, the one that was flagged as duplicate **might** have more information than the original post.

Also, from [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841)'s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844):

> **Should duplicates be deleted?**
>   In general, no: most duplicates stay
>   around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different
>   wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an
>   answer may use different wording too.
>
> Duplicates that are word-for-word copies or that are so poorly written
>   that they are not useful may be deleted by users with sufficient
>   privilege.

In your question:

> You would think linking A to B would raise the page rank of B. Why is
>   A still higher?

Maybe, just maybe, the content of A itself is enough to solve one's problem. If we are solving problems here, I don't think there is an issue, as **long as A is correct**.