# Show list of duplicates of the question

Tags: feature-request

Another [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313350/site-policy-regarding-duplicates-where-first-google-result-is-the-duplicate) on Meta made me think: would it be a good idea to show the "ring" of duplicates for the question on screen? It's possible that the duplicates have slightly different answers that could be useful to whoever found the question. A little drop-down or a tab on the question could provide a list without being too noticeable.

Comment: There is a "Linked" section to the right.  That would include duplicates linked directly.  It would also include any other post linked to that one, in either direction.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, linked section doesn't show, which questions are duplicates https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283526/show-duplicate-status-next-to-titles-on-right-linked-related-questions-panels

Comment: Possible duplicate of  meta SE https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183490/duplicate-questions-sidebar?rq=1

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim a question can't be closed as a dupe of a question on another site.

Comment: Every question has its own “linked” page accessible via the URL [`https://[site]/questions/linked/[questionID]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/313699). This list includes `[duplicate]` in the linked questions’ titles.